# MaterialCardView with MaterialShapeDrawable

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview, android-styles, material-components-android

I want to achieve this:

[image]

So I thought I could use a `MaterialShapeDrawable` to apply that transformation:

```
binding.card.background = MaterialShapeDrawable(
    ShapeAppearanceModel.builder()
        .setAllCornerSizes(5.dpToPx().toFloat())
        .setTopEdge(object : TriangleEdgeTreatment(7.dpToPx().toFloat(), false){
            override fun getEdgePath(length: Float, center: Float, interpolation: Float, shapePath: ShapePath) {
                super.getEdgePath(length, 12.dpToPx().toFloat(), interpolation, shapePath)
            }
        })
        .build()
).apply {
    fillColor = resourcesProvider().colorStateListFromAttr(R.attr.colorSurface, R.style.App_CardView)
}
```

But unfortunately it changes nothing. So I've tried to apply to a direct children like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardElevation="10dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"> //without this margin nothing is shown
```

And it kinda works but I get a funky result due to `app:cardElevation="10dp"` (which is needed):

[image]

So my questions are:
1 - Is it possible to apply transformations to a CardView? if so, how?
2 - How can I solve this "shadow on top" problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Elevation of 10dp is too much and that's why that funky shadow. You've to reduce the elevation to 3dp to get that desired output. Or, If  10dp is must to use, I'd suggest to use it in a parent layout with padding, give it a elevation, and reduce your card's elevation. This way your cardView's shadow will be reduced but it's still be elevated that much. Or, You can use [Bubble](https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView#bubble) view or you can search the repo for the code of the bubble view if you do not want to use the complete Repo. I use it because its shadows look more real than CardView's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are drawing outside the `CardView`, in the parent view you should use something like:

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:clipChildren="false"
      android:clipToPadding="false"
      android:padding="16dp"
      ..>

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
         app:cardElevation="2dp"
         ../>
```

Then apply the changes to **`ShapeAppearanceModel`** but getting the existing `ShapeAppearanceModel` used by the cardview (in your code you are replacing the existing `MaterialShapeDrawable` not only applying a change in the `ShapeAppearanceModel`):

```
cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setTopEdge(new TriangleEdgeTreatment(size, false){

            @Override public void getEdgePath(float length, float center, float interpolation,
              @NonNull ShapePath shapePath) {
              //...... your implementation
            }
          }
        )
        .build());
```

[image]

Starting with the **`1.2.0-beta01`** you can also use the `OffsetEdgeTreatment` with a `MarkerEdgeTreatment`.

Something like:

```
MarkerEdgeTreatment markerEdgeTreatment = new MarkerEdgeTreatment(size);
OffsetEdgeTreatment offsetEdgeTreatment = new OffsetEdgeTreatment(markerEdgeTreatment,offset);

cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel()
            .toBuilder()
            .setTopEdge(offsetEdgeTreatment)
            .build());
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've a problem, if I add `.setTopEdge( TriangleEdgeTreatment(7.dpToPx().toFloat(), false))`the card doesn't show up, if I comment that line it shows (of course without the top triangle). Any hint?

Comment: @GuilhE Did you add a padding in the parent view?

Comment: Yes, a LinearLayout just like in your example.

Comment: With material =  "1.2.1" it's working as expected :)