# how to create triangle gap on cardview?

Tags: android, android-cardview, material-components-android, android-shape

how can I create a triangle gap on the bottom of a cardview like this in android studio?

[image: a cardview like this]

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/10024/android-recyclerview-android-cardview-example-tutorial refer this site

Comment: the link that you preferred is just about simple cardviews. the cardview that I want to create has a gap on the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `TriangleEdgeTreatment` included in the Material Components Library.

Just use a simple layout like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        .../>
```

then apply the `TriangleEdgeTreatment` on the bottom edge:

```
    MaterialCardView cardView = findViewById(R.id.card);
    cardView.setShapeAppearanceModel(cardView.getShapeAppearanceModel().toBuilder()
            .setBottomEdge(new TriangleEdgeTreatment(40.f, true))
            .build());
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your perfect answer. when I set shape appearance to cardview, it has invisibled.

Comment: @MohammadMirdar which version of material components are you using?

Comment: yes. I changed my material components version to the latest alpha version and it worked fine. thank you so much

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti 
Currently setBottomEdge is positioning the triangle at the bottom center of the cardview.
Is it possible to set the triangle position, i mean put the triangle at the start or end of the cardview or add some custom margin?

Comment: @Balflear Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62020063/2016562) and use the OffsetEdgeTreatment together with TriangleEdgeTreatment